# find and remove a word from sentence(in between the word matching) python

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have sentence like below

```
mainsentence="My words aren't available give didn't give apple and did happening me"

stopwords=['are','did','word', 'able','give','happen']
```

want to remove if any word matchs the words in between(ex: "word" should match "words" and remove it, "did" should match "didn't" and remove it, 'able' should remove "available" because 'able' word is in 'available'

```
finalsentence="My apple and me"
```

tried with below code but

```
querywords = mainsentence.split()
resultwords  = [word for word in querywords if word.lower() not in stopwords]
result = ' '.join(resultwords)
print(result)
```

but its only working with exact match.

Please help me.

Comment: The problem you have here, is you want to have partial matches, but `a` is going to be a partial match for most of your words.

Comment: Also, `happen` should be in the `finalsentence`

Comment: @tituszban: Corrected the question.

Comment: It sounds like you will need to check not against your list of words, but against a list of synonyms of your list of words.  There are several ways to do this, one is with PyDictionary: https://pypi.org/project/PyDictionary/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following thing:

```
>>> ' '.join([word for word in mainsentence.split() if not any([stopword in word for stopword in stopwords])])
'My apple and me'
```

EDIT: this doesn't need to be a two way check, just see if word contains stopword
EDIT2: Updated result with updated question parameters

Not case sensitive version:

```
' '.join([word for word in mainsentence.split() if not any([stopword.lower() in word.lower() for stopword in stopwords])])
```

Comment: Note that it will be case sensitive.

Comment: You also do not need to create the intermediate `list` within `any()`.

Answer (score 2):

The following code would meet your requirements as stated in the question, but it is not likely what you want as result.
The general infrastructure of the code should be correct, but you may want to change the condition for partial match (`stopword in testword`):

```
def filter_out_stopwords(text, stopwords):
    result = []
    for word in text.split():
        testword = word.lower()
        flag = True
        for stopword in stopwords:
            if stopword in testword:
                flag = False
                break
        if flag:
            result.append(word)
    return result


' '.join(filter_out_stopwords("My words aren't available give didn't give apple and did happening me", ['are', 'did', 'word', 'able', 'give', 'happen']))
# "My apple and me"
```

or, using list comprehension and `all()` (`any()` could be used equivalently):

```
def filter_out_stopwords(text, stopwords):                                                                                                   
    return [
        word for word in text.split()
        if all(stopword not in word.lower() for stopword in stopwords)]


' '.join(filter_out_stopwords("My words aren't available give didn't give apple and did happening me", ['are', 'did', 'word', 'able', 'give', 'happen']))
# "My apple and me"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use power of regular expression for theese kind of problems.

```py
import re
```

You can get all the mathing words like this:

```py
words = re.findall(r'[a-z]*did[a-z]*', mainsentence)
```

You can also replace them:

```py
re.sub(r'[a-z]*able[a-z]* ', '', mainsentence)
```

So final answer:

```py
mainsentence="My words aren't available give didn't give apple and did happening me"

stopwords=['are','did','word', 'able','give','happen']

for word in stopwords:
    mainsentence = re.sub(fr'[a-z\']*{word}[a-z\']* ', '', mainsentence)
# My apple and me
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have can have a sustainable solution in following steps.

1. Expand the words like I've -> I have, didn't -> did not. Look into [pycontractions](https://pypi.org/project/pycontractions/).
2. Use lemmas of words to get base form of each word, i.e change forms of a word to their root form. Example: playing, plays, played become play. Lets call current state of the corpus as clean corpus. Look into [lemmatization](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-lemmatization-with-nltk/).
3. Now remove any stop words from the clean corpus.

You might also find a [text cleaning module](https://github.com/AhsanAliLodhi/textcleaner/blob/master/cleaner.py) that I wrote interesting, which also includes spell correction and can be use to make a text cleaning pipeline.